# what are good AI paper topics

Tags: artificial-intelligence

Currently finishing an AI class for my Computer Science degree, the final is a 20 page research paper on a specific branch/topic in AI. There are several topics I am interested in, especially when i found out someone used A* to 'solve' Super Mario. However, I am having trouble deciding what topics would be easiest and fastest to write that long of a paper, as I only have a week to do it.

Also, the paper is supposed to be a 'technical discussion', I have only written papers for English type classes, and am not sure what he means by that, any advice?

If you have a topic that is not hard to code, I can cut the paper as low as 8 pages if I have a programming element, this paper would need a 'results' section, which Im guessing is a 'what did you learn by coding this' type section? correct me if Im wrong

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in path-finding like A* why don't you consider developing a maze solving bot? you could also generate the mazes uses an algorithm such as Ellers algorithm. there should be a whole host of discussions on the subject as it is both popular in software and robotics.